# Bea 8 shared library error

Tags: java, shared-libraries, weblogic8.x, bea

I have a problem with a shared library in bea 8.
I want to create a jar for managed the response from a webservice,
So I create an ear file for a shared library that have this structure:

```
mySharedLib.ear
     lib
        wsClient.jar
        some.jar
     META-INF
        application.xml
        MANIFEST.MF
     mySharedLib.jar
```

In application.xml I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
  <display-name>
    My Shared Lib
  </display-name>
  <module>
    <java>mySharedLib.jar</java>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```

And in the manifest I have this:

```
Implementation-Title: mySharedLib
Implementation-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: mySharedLib
Specification-Version: 1.0
Extension-Name: mySharedLib
```

Then I deploy this ear as library on admin server and in managed server.

In my webapp in the WEB-INF\weblogic.xml I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-web-app PUBLIC "-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 8.1//EN" "http://www.bea.com/servers/wls810/dtd/weblogic810-web-jar.dtd">
<weblogic-web-app>
    <session-descriptor>
        <session-param>
            <param-name>PersistentStoreType</param-name>
            <param-value>replicated_if_clustered</param-value>
        </session-param>
        <session-param>
            <param-name>TimeoutSecs</param-name>
            <param-value>1800</param-value>
        </session-param>
    </session-descriptor>
       <library-ref>
        <library-name>mySharedLib</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>
        <exact-match>true</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

When I deploy the webapp on server I retrive this error:

```
####<Jul 29, 2015 7:26:20 PM CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <bea01> <Server02> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1438190780090> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1438190773715' for task '1388'. Error is: 'weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved Webapp Library references for "weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@2bc856f - appName: 'WebApp', name: 'WebApp.war', context-path: '/WebApp'", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: mySharedLib, Specification-Version: 1, Implementation-Version: 1.0, exact-match: true].'
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: [J2EE:160149]Error while processing library references. Unresolved Webapp Library references for "weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@2bc856f - appName: 'WebApp', name: 'WebApp.war', context-path: '/WebApp'", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: mySharedLib, Specification-Version: 1, Implementation-Version: 1.0, exact-match: true].
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.CheckLibraryReferenceFlow.prepare(CheckLibraryReferenceFlow.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:615)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:147)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:61)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(RedeployOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.doPrepare(RedeployOperation.java:118)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:719)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1186)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:248)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:157)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:157)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:45)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:464)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to correct the error? We need to see some effort from you; we're not going to just debug your code for you.

Comment: First I deploy only the jar mySharedLib.jar like shared library and the manifest is the same that I posted, and I give the exeption.
Than I read in some forum the target of shared lib must be the admin server and the managed server, so I modified the deploy, but the error remain the same. Finally I create an ear from the jar but nothig change. This is the step for resolve the problem, what I posted is the last situation